# Convert es6 to es5 using babel then Bundle with Browserify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im using es6 feature like import and classes , now i understand that the browser doesn't support import feature and i read  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28827915/5623124). that i need to convert the es6 code into es5 , and after it i need to bundle them using Browserify or gulp, webpack, browserify, etc.  Now the question going like that: the code changes everytime and i want to check my results , do i need to repeat of this procedure everytime before i want to see the results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every time you change something you need to rebuild it unfortunately. Take a look at [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) or for more complex projects you might consider using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) or any other task runner to automate the process.

```
// first install watchify, babelify and babel-preset-es2015
watchify script.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

Comment: Okay but before i rebuild it i need to translate es6 to es5 and then budle it ... there is a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Take a look at example I put here, there is babelify (babel plugin for browserify) with es2015 preset included - that will do translation before packaging

Comment: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory ".." what can cause this problem and secondly do i need to give the script.js before i babel it to es5 right?

Comment: I think I had this problem with "could not find es2015" when I had browserify and others installed locally for project and script that was packaged had path unrelated to project - for some reason it looks for node_modules in script directory or any parent directory of script. probably it's enough to install preset globally or move sources to directory where you have node_modules. if you're running watchify/browserify with babelify transform and es2015 preset (as in my example) you don't have to do anything extra, output package is what you can use in browser already.

Comment: well it worked out , but now i face another problem with your solution its convert one file into bundle , but what if i have alot of files , and lets say im using angular so i have templates and one index page who changes with ajax so the sources for scripts need to load once on the first page for the whole application, how can i solve this problem , when here i bundle only one file .. "script.js"

Comment: browserify parses require / import statements so everything you require() will be included in the bundle, additionally you can specify more than one file (i.e. `src/*/**.js` to include any js file in src directory). I don't know how to include templates for angular as I'm not using it, but google it, for sure there is some way.

Comment: I tried installing watchify, babelify and babel-preset-es2015 but getting "Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions".  I am using "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",     "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",     "babelify": "^10.0.0" and "watchify": "^3.11.1". Is this answer still valid?