# Do I need require js when I use babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im experimenting with ES6, and Im using gulp to build and babel to transpile to ES5. The output is not being run in node, just linked to from a .htm file with a  tag. Im thinking I need to add

```
<script src='require.js'></script>
```

or something like that.

Im trying to import / export.

```
////////////////scripts.js
import {Circle} from 'shapes';

c = new Circle(4);

console.log(c.area());


/////////////////shapes.js
export class Circle {

    circle(radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    area() {
        return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;
    } 

}
```

Error is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Refers to this (after .pipe(babel()) in gulp)

```
var _shapes = require('shapes');
```

Comment: Yes, because `require` doesn't exist in the browser, you need to use some build tool like Require.js, Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: Ahh, adding browserify to my googling got me the answer, thank you.

Comment: FWIW, note that the error message does not indicate that you need require.js . Babel converts modules to CommonJS by default, which is what Node uses and which defines a `require` function (again, nothing to do with require.js). However, [you can tell Babel to convert modules to something else](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/), e.g. AMD or UMD, which would then work with require.js. Either way, you need a system to load modules in the browser, because the browser doesn't provide one by default (yet).

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125554/javascript-6to5-export-module-usage

Comment: For people coming here in around 2020, you can use the 'transform-modules-amd' plugin without other libraries. Refer https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-amd.

Answer (score 152):

> ## Do I need require js when I use babel?

You might need some module loader, but it is not necessary RequireJS. You have several options. The following will help you to get started.

---

## [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/) with [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel)

Rollup is a next-generation JavaScript module bundler. It understands ES2015 modules natively, and will produce a bundle that doesn't need any module loader to operate. Unused exports will be trimmed from the output, it's called tree-shaking.

Now I personally recommend using rollupjs, as it produces the clearest output, and is easy to setup, however, it gives a different aspect to the answer. All the other approaches do the following:

1. Compile the ES6 code with babel, use the module format of your choice
2. Concatenate the compiled modules alongside with a module loader OR use a bundler that will traverse the dependencies for you.

With rollupjs things doesn't really work this way. Here, rollup is the first step, instead of babel. It only understands ES6 modules by default. You must give an entry module of which the dependencies will be traversed and concatenated. As ES6 allows multiple named exports in a module, rollupjs is smart enough to strip unused exports, thus shrinking bundle size. Unfortunately rollupjs-s parser doesn't understand >ES6 syntax, so ES7 modules have to be compiled before rollup parses them, but the compilation should not affect the ES6 imports. It is done by using the `rollup-plugin-babel` plugin with the `babel-preset-es2015-rollup` preset (this preset is the same as the es2015 one, except the module transformer and the external-helpers plugin). So rollup will do the following with your modules if correctly set up:

1. Reads your ES6-7 module from the filesystem
2. The babel plugin compiles it to ES6 in memory
3. rollup parses the ES6 code for imports and exports (using acorn parser, compiled into rollup)
4. it traverses the whole graph, and creates a single bundle (which still might have external dependencies, and the entry's exports might be exported, in a format of your choice)

#### Example nodejs build:

```
// setup by `npm i rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-external-helpers --save-dev`

// build.js:
require("rollup").rollup({
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  plugins: [
    require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
      "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
      "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
    })
  ]
}).then(bundle => {
  var result = bundle.generate({
    // output format - 'amd', 'cjs', 'es6', 'iife', 'umd'
    format: 'iife'
  });

  require("fs").writeFileSync("./dist/bundle.js", result.code);
  // sourceMaps are supported too!
}).then(null, err => console.error(err));
```

#### Example grunt build with [grunt-rollup](https://github.com/chrisprice/grunt-rollup)

```
// setup by `npm i grunt grunt-rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-external-helpers --save-dev`

// gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-rollup");
  grunt.initConfig({
    "rollup": {
      "options": {
        "format": "iife",
        "plugins": [
          require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
            "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
            "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
          })
        ]
      },
      "dist": {
        "files": {
          "./dist/bundle.js": ["./src/main.js"]
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Example gulp build with [gulp-rollup](https://github.com/mcasimir/gulp-rollup)

```
// setup by `npm i gulp gulp-rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-external-helpers --save-dev`

// gulpfile.js
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    rollup     = require('gulp-rollup');

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/**/*.js')
    // transform the files here.
    .pipe(rollup({
      // any option supported by Rollup can be set here.
      "format": "iife",
      "plugins": [
        require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
          "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
          "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
        })
      ],
      entry: './src/main.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

---

## [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) + [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Babel has a neat package called [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify). It's usage is simple and straightforward:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babelify babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
$ npm install -g browserify
$ browserify src/script.js -o bundle.js \
  -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

or you can use it from node.js:

```
$ npm install --save-dev browserify babelify babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react

...

var fs = require("fs");
var browserify = require("browserify");
browserify(["./src/script.js"])
  .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));
```

This will transpile and concatenate your code at once. Browserify's `.bundle` will include a nice little CommonJS loader, and will organize your transpiled modules into functions. You can even have relative imports.

#### Example:

```
// project structure
.
+-- src/
|   +-- library/
|   |   \-- ModuleA.js
|   +-- config.js
|   \-- script.js
+-- dist/
\-- build.js
...

// build.js
var fs = require("fs");
var browserify = require("browserify");
browserify(["./src/script.js"])
  .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("dist/bundle.js"));

// config.js
export default "Some config";

// ModuleA.js
import config from '../config';
export default "Some nice export: " + config;

// script.js
import ModuleA from './library/ModuleA';
console.log(ModuleA);
```

To compile just run `node build.js` in your project root.

---

## [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) + [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/)

Compile all your code using babel. I recommend you to use the amd module transformer (called `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd` in babel 6). After that bundle your compiled sources with WebPack.

**WebPack 2 is out!** It understands native ES6 modules, [and will perform (or rather simulate) tree shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) using [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili)-s builtin dead code elimination. For now (September 2016) I would still suggest to use rollup with babel, although my opinion might change with the first release of WebPack 2. Feel free to discuss your opinions in the comments.

---

## Custom compilation pipeline

Sometimes you want to have more control over the compilation process. You can implement your own pipeline like this:

First, you have to configure babel to use amd modules. By default babel transpiles to CommonJS modules, which is a little complicated to handle in the browser, although browserify manages to handle them in a nice way.

- Babel 5: use `{ modules: 'amdStrict', ... }` option
- Babel 6: use the `es2015-modules-amd` plugin

Don't forget to turn on the `moduleIds: true` option.

Check the transpiled code for generated modul names, there are often mismatches between defined and required modules. See [sourceRoot and moduleRoot](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/).

Finally, you have to have some kind of module loader, but it isn't necessairy requirejs. There is [almondjs](https://github.com/jrburke/almond), a tiny require shim that works well. You can even implement your own:

```
var __modules = new Map();

function define(name, deps, factory) {
    __modules.set(name, { n: name, d: deps, e: null, f: factory });
}

function require(name) {
    const module = __modules.get(name);
    if (!module.e) {
        module.e = {};
        module.f.apply(null, module.d.map(req));
    }
    return module.e;

    function req(name) {
        return name === 'exports' ? module.e : require(name);
    }
}
```

At the end, you can just concatenate the loader shim and the compiled modules together, and running an uglify on that.

---

## Babel's boilerplate code is duplicated in every module

By default, most of the above methods compile each module with babel individually, and then concatenate them together. That's what babelify does too. But if you look at the compiled code, you see that babel inserts lots of boilerplate at the beginning of each file, most of them are duplicated across all files.

To prevent this you can use the [`babel-plugin-transform-runtime`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) plugin.

Comment: This is so bloody thorough; thank you. Re: the duplicate Babel boilerplate per file - would it be correct to assume that gzip would all but negate that?

Comment: I never measured it myself, but I would assume that one would minify the bundle before distribution, and the minification will probably find different names for locals, so they will not be exactly the same. Gzip should find the common parts (resulting in a good compression ratio), but the browser still has to parse them individually. Ultimately it shouldn't be a noticeable overhead, but there will be people like me who just doesn't like duplicated code.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the response. It would probably make a lot of sense, also, in cases where you had to back up or track the output code in version control (where uncompressed file size multiplies) or where you'd like the output to be unminified for whatever reason.

Comment: [gulp-rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rollup) might be a good addition to this list too

Comment: @GGG Added gulp example. Unfortunately none of the examples work at the moment on windows, see the explanation on the top the codes.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I have a build system with gulp, gulp-rollup and rollup-babel running on windows and it works perfectly. I don't know which errors you might have thought.

Comment: @GGG well, don't update your npm packages now :D I have just tried on a clean project: `It looks like your Babel configuration specifies a module transformer. Please disable it. If you're using the "es2015" preset, consider using "es2015-rollup" instead.` `modify-babel-preset` somehow failed to find the appropriate plugins. I am considering to remove the mention of es2015-rollup as modify-babel-preset breaks really often nowadays.

Comment: @TamasHegedus [This](https://gist.github.com/GGG-KILLER/a058032223142252d7cb3acc957c8369) is my setup, if it interests you (also deleting your `.babelrc` file might solve your problem, it was taking priority over the parameters I passed on my gulpfile)

Comment: @GGG As I see neither do you use the es2015-rollup preset. If the es2015-rollup preset doesn't get fixed in days, i will just change to a similar config to yours.

Comment: I don't get why Babel isn't able to do this on its own. We are using Babel to concatenate and minify all our JS in a single file. Adding a polyfill for, say, `Promise`, should be as simple as including one more file to the list. Using an entire module loader seems to be such an overkill... :/
+1 anyway

Answer (score 8):

**barebones webpack 2**

1) If this is your root directory:

index.html

```
<html>
  ...
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  ...
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
import { Circle } from './shapes.js';
  ...
```

shapes.js

```
export class Circle {
  ...
}
```

2) have node installed [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)

3) run the following command in your terminal:

```
$ npm install -g webpack
```

5) in your root directory run the following:

```
$ webpack scripts.js bundle.js
```

You should now have a file called bundle.js in your root directory which will be the file your index.html will consume.  This is a minimalistic bundling feature from webpack.  You can learn more [here](https://webpack.js.org/)

Answer (score 6):

`require` does not exist in the browser, so this error is expected. You need to use something like require.js or Browserify.