# SystemJS, Babel and jspm

Tags: javascript, es6-module-loader

I was recently introduced to JavaScript Module Loaders, AMD and CommonJS specifications, and SystemJS. I have some questions:

1. In the demos and examples I've seen, SystemJS was used together with Babel transpiler via configurations. Is it a common practice to use them together or separately? Like using ES6 imports with SystemJS and then transpiling the code as a part of the build process?
2. Just how does SystemJS integrate with Babel? Does it transpile my modules when I try to import them?
3. I've seen SystemJS used with jspm. What are the benefits to using jspm with SystemJS instead of npm/bower?
4. Isn't SystemJS somewhat large/heavy? What do I lose if I roll up my own slim AMD implementation that adresses my needs?

Comment: point 4: SystemJS is pretty heavyweight, itt will even generate 404 http responses while searching for the right modules to load. It can be configured properly though, but basically I would only use it for development. For production, dont use AMD, use RollupJS bundler. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel