# Using babel to transpile to es3 (safari compliant)

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I am new to babel.

I set it up like this:

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "es2017"]
}
```

gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/3rd/*'])
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

However this seems to be compiling to es5 which is not fully supported in Safari.

Is there a way to set target? So it can compile to ES3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Babel does not support transpiling to ES3.

Your options are:

1. Compile to ES5 and then use [ES5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).
2. Use a different transpiler. [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) and [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) both support ES6 as input and ES3 as output.

**Note:** The "ES5" code that Babel produces may not work in all browsers, as it may include features not present in ES5 (see [caveats](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/) for more info). In other words, since you're targeting even older browsers, you'll also need [Babel polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) as well as ES5 shim.

Comment: I did `npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill` then in my js file I did: `import 'babel/polyfill';` however in the transpiled file I see: `'use strict'; require('babel/polyfill');` this will obviously not work when I paste it to jsfiddle.net - I get `require is not defiend` - can you please help me understand why its not properly transpiling?

Comment: This is a bit of a separate issue - in short, you need a module loader. I'd recommend [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel) as it gives a **very** thorough overview of what your options are in this regard.

Comment: Thanks fastanis! But I thought babel provided module loader no?

Comment: Sadly, no. Babel can only transform ES6 modules (`import` keyword) into another module system (such as AMD or SystemJS).