# Babel - IE8 inherit issue with Object.create

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill

Unfortunately, I need to deal with IE8 compatibility nightmares and after few hours of fixing troubles one after another I'm in a dead-end, hope someone can help me.

`Babel` implements inheritance thru this method:

```
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if ("function" != typeof superClass && null !== superClass) throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: !1,
            writable: !0,
            configurable: !0
        }
    }), superClass && (Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass);
}
```

When I run this code on IE8 I'm getting this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method` that refers to the usage of `Object.create`

I tried to look for a plugin and different settings of Babel but couldn't find something that actually solve it.

Do someone know how to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried setting babel to output ES3 code instead of ES5? Otherwise you'll need to load an ES5 shim.

Comment: yes, of course, the only thing has left is the inheritance issue, BTW, when I'm using the TypeScript inheritance it works fine, looks like babel's one is problematic in IE

Comment: Apparently [Babel cannot transpile to es3, but Typescript can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40205612/2964675). Probably following what is suggested in the link may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as possible: Object.create is not available in all Browsers (IE < 10, older Opera and Chrome editions)

Comment: The question was not what the issue was, but rather how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by create this simple polyfill:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(o, properties) {
        if (typeof o !== 'object' && typeof o !== 'function') throw new TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object: ' + o);
        else if (o === null) throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support 'null' as the first argument.");

        //if (typeof properties != 'undefined') throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support a second argument.");

        function F() {}

        F.prototype = o;

        return new F();
    };
}
```

ref: [Object.create not supported in ie8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020265/object-create-not-supported-in-ie8)

I commented the `if (typeof properties != 'undefined')` line because if not, i'm getting the following error:

> This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't
>   support a second argument.

I think it's not so safe because if some consumer will use it with the second argument (`properties`) it may cause an unexpected behavior but for my use case it's ok.

So far so good.