# The correct usage of import directive in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What do I need to make the following work?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/babel">
    import React from 'react';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In its current form it produces an error:

```
Inline Babel script:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:14
    at run (babel.js:61531)
    at check (babel.js:61597)
    at loadScripts (babel.js:61638)
    at runScripts (babel.js:61668)
    at transformScriptTags (babel.js:336)
    at babel.js:327
```

This form does not work too:

```
import React from 'react.production.min';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need require js when I use babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel) --- Although I don't know if that question talks about non-transpiled code.

Comment: Since you're not in a module context, you can use `React` directly as it's been defined on the global object by linking the scripts directly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the link is definitely valuable information, but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @Paul which version are you using? Could you provide an [interactive stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1218980)?

Comment: I've changed it to a stack snippet. 

Comment: Ok now I understand that stack snippets is a formatting on StackOverflow and not some browser function that will help me to debug JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a React application with client-side babel: You **don't** use `import`.

`import React from 'react';` is **replaced** by the first two `<script>` elements you have in your HTML document.

---

If you want to use modules with React, you'd be better off taking "Setup Option 2" in [the React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and putting together a local development environment that uses babel at *build time* instead of at run time.

Comment: So, I conclude that EVERY include in examples belongs to server side Javascript. Right?

Comment: @paul I upvoted your comment, and you can develop a client-side only application with node.js only for the local toolchain. Once built, you can move the resulting static files to a CDN and voilà, no Node server needed at all!

Comment: Please understand me. I just started to try React.js and all the first examples require to use Node.js, but this information is mostly omitted as a matter of course. When they provide examples they do not mention on which side (Server/Client) to apply them. I never worked with server side JS.

Comment: @Paul I totally get you, I've been there as well! I think this feeling is worse when diving directly into a specific framework as the documentation and most tutorials assume you're already familiar with the ecosystem and/or other frameworks. Good luck!