# Use babel result in html

Tags: javascript, html, npm, babeljs

I am trying to understand magic of frontend development and I still hit the wall while doing simple stuff.

I created and published simple npm package `kosciej16-paczka`

```
exports.printMsg = function() {
  console.log("This is a message from the demo package");
}
```

Now I want to use that anyhow. I created new package with `npm init` and wrote index.js

```
import printMsg from "kosciej16-paczka"

printMsg()
```

and som.html

```
<body>
    HA
    <script src=index.js>
    </script>
</body>
```

Then I read something that the browser cannot understand `import` syntax and I need to use different tool to translate the code. Ok, started to read about `babel`. Walk throught the [tutorial](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage) and run `npx babel src --out-dir lib` with config provided there.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.6.5"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Which created new `index.js`

```
"use strict";

var _kosciej16Paczka = _interopRequireDefault(require("kosciej16-paczka"));
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
(0, _kosciej16Paczka.default)();
```

So I tried to use that file in `<script>` tag but got an error about `require is not defined`.

That confused me totally - shouldn't `babel` functionality be creating code that browsers can run? What is the `babel` output for then?

I would be very gratefull for some up to date tutorial that explains things step by step and actually works,.

Comment: You need to show your babel config. Babel can compile to various targets.

Comment: Used one provided in the tutorial, updated the question

Comment: You need either es modules with `script type="module"`, or a bundler like webpack. Babel doesn't transform the module loader used just converts from one version of ecmascript to another. Your question is mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel