# How to install a react library in a hybrid react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a website created using vanilla Js. Now, I am trying to add React to it. I followed the steps from the official documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). Everything works fine. I am able to use react in my project.
But now, I need to use a react library ([react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)).

I tried running `npm install react-responsive-carousel`. But I am not able to import this in my React component.

I compile my react files using `npx babel react-js --out-dir js --presets @babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react --watch`. It compiles the react import statements into require statements and I get the error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"` in tthe browser

How can I use react libraries in my project?

Comment: _"But I am not able to import this in my React component."_ - why?

Comment: Updated the question with the error.

Comment: babel probably isn't transpiling `react-responsive-carousel`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need require js when I use babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel)

Comment: The issue is in the import statement itself. The issue is there with all libraries. In fact, I am using React by adding CDN link in html (as explained in documentation) and importing it using `const { Component } = React;`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have package file in you project? I think you can initialize npm and once you have package file,you can install the packages.
Note- You should have node js installed

Comment: Also on the same page (https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) check section to add JSX to project. These are same steps I mentioned above

Comment: I have already added this. I can install packages using npm but error is in the import statement.