# Why do I have to use vinyl-source-stream with gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I am trying to use gulp and browserify to transform my `.jsx` files into `.js` files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

gulp.task('js', function () {
  browserify('public/javascripts/src/app.jsx')
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts/dist'))
});
```

```

The above threw `Arguments to path.resolve must be strings`. I managed to get around it by using `vinyl-source-stream`

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
...
.bundle()
.source('app.js')
...
```

Why does this work? I am fairly new to nodejs and gulp. After reading the README of the project and the source code, I am still confused. Any help?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I think that reading this article [**gulp**
The vision, history, and future of the project](https://medium.com/@contrahacks/gulp-3828e8126466) can help you to clarify a few concepts.

Basically you can say that **vinyl-source-stream** convert the [*readable stream* you get from browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bbundlecb) into a *vinyl stream* that is what gulp is expecting to get.

A **vinyl stream** is a *Virtual file format*, and it is fundamental for **Gulp**. Thanks to *vinyl streams* Gulp doesn't need to write temporary files between different transformations. And this is one of the main advantages it has over **Grunt**.

Answer (score 4):

This module is just a bridge that makes it simple to use conventional text streams such as this in combination with gulp.